# Angular - Ternary operator with a ternary operator response

Tags: javascript, angular, conditional-operator

I have a ternary operator in my angular HTML. I'm having difficulty with the formatting. If the value equals the files length, it should return `Good`, if it doesn't I need to check some custom values. I check to see if the custom value exists (`customs?.album_title`) and then determine what to show. If both options were strings, it works completely fine. However, I need `My Text` to prepend the `customs.album_title` value and I'm not entirely sure how to do that. As you can see in the example below (which is naturally incorrect), the result would be `customs?.album_title` as a string, opposed to `My Text` + whatever the `customs.album_title` value is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{{ value == files.length ? 'Good' : customs?.album_title ? 'My Text customs.album_title' : 'String Two' }}
```

Comment: `'My Text customs.album_title'` -> `'My Text ' + customs.album_title`?

Comment: Thanks Vlaz. I had tried that with no luck I'm afraid.

Comment: @Que what do you mean by "no luck"???  That would totally work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry that it didn't work. When I try that, Angular doesn't build. I would love it to work, obviously.

Comment: @Que What error do you get then?

Comment: The error was regarding modules that couldn't be built. Unfortunately, nothing specific to the text implementation above. It didn't make sense. After restarting visual code, the above works (which I had tried before). Slightly irritating. @Vlaz, thanks for the response. If you can create an answer, i'll mark it as complete.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean like this (using ${var})

```
{{ value == files.length ? 'Good' : customs?.album_title ? `My Text ${customs.album_title}` : 'String Two' }}
```

I'm not sure but I think [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are not yet supported by Angular on HTML templates.

So for now, you can try to solve it by string concatenation

```
{{ value == files.length ? 'Good' : customs?.album_title ? ('My Text ' + customs.album_title) : 'String Two' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
{{ value == files.length ? 'Good' : (customs?.album_title ? (('My Text ') + customs.album_title) : 'String Two') }}
```